# Launch agent runs the script every 10 seconds

Tags: bash, launchd

I have a launch agent that runs a bash script whenever a usb device is connected. I want it to run just once, but when i connect the device, the script keeps running every 10 seconds.

Here is the plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN    http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd >
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.program</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Users/Peter/Desktop/test1.sh</string>
    <key>LaunchEvents</key>
    <dict>
      <key>com.apple.iokit.matching</key>
        <dict>
          <key>com.apple.device-attach</key>
            <dict>
              <key>idProduct</key>
              <integer>1476</integer>
              <key>idVendor</key>
              <integer>1356</integer>
              <key>IOProviderClass</key>
              <string>IOUSBDevice</string>
              <key>IOMatchLaunchStream</key>
              <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
open -a "Spotify";
sleep 11;
```

I added sleep 11, as I read that the script needs to run at least 10 seconds to let launchd think its done its task. This however doesn't help any.

In terminal running `launchctl list com.example.program` gives:

```
"LimitLoadToSessionType" = "Aqua";
"Label" = "com.example.program";
"TimeOut" = 30;
"OnDemand" = true;
"LastExitStatus" = 0;
"Program" = "/Users/Peter/Desktop/test1.sh";
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, launchd starts programs when their launch conditions are met, *and then restarts them if they exit or crash*. To keep it from relaunching your script, just add `<key>KeepAlive</key><false/>` to your .plist (and then unload and reload it). It might also be necessary to add `<key>AbandonProcessGroup</key><true/>` to keep launchd from killing the "leftover" Spotify process (though I think it'll work without this).

Comment: Unfortunately adding those keys doesn't make a difference. What's interesting is that i don't see those new keys when I run launchctl list com.example.program in terminal. Is that normal?

Comment: @JohnSmith It sounds like you need to reload the .plist. Try `launchctl unload /path/to/com.example.program.plist`, and then `launchctl unload /path/to/com.example.program.plist`. (Note: do *not* use `sudo` with these; that would treat it as a daemon, not an agent.)